# Issue with Azure DocumentDb host connection

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I have not been able to connect to the DocumentDb host on azure with MongoDb client, I followed the link of [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/documentdb/documentdb-mongodb-mongochef)

[image]

Then the error message fron mongochef client:

```
Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting for a server that matches ReadPreferenceServerSelector{readPreference=primary}.
Client view of cluster state is
{type=UNKNOWN, servers=[
   {address=tatico-nosql.documents.azure.com:10250, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception=
      {com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket},
       caused by {java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out}
    }
 ]
```

Comment: Please add more details, e.g. your code, errors, what you tried to fix it etc.

Comment: hi @Mikhail ;
Then the error message fron mongochef client:
_Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting for a server that matches ReadPreferenceServerSelector{readPreference=primary}. Client view of cluster state is {type=UNKNOWN, servers=[{address=tatico-nosql.documents.azure.com:10250, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket}, caused by

 {java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out}}]_

Comment: @oswaldomartinez - please don't bury those types of details in comments. You should instead edit your answer. Please see the edit I just did, to properly include your error message.

Comment: So, with the info you provided, there's not enough detail to answer your question. Did you enable the MongoDB API when you created your database? Also, what does your connection string look like (please do NOT include your *real* credentials)? Please edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled IP access control? If yes, please also add your client IP address to allowed list of IP address ranges as below.

[image]